# can a android or apple phone broadcast and receive Bluetooth BLE signals simultaneously?

Tags: android, ios, ibeacon, altbeacon, eddystone

I wish to develop an application for android and IOS and would like to know if it is theoretically possible for my app to broadcast Ibeacon or Eddystone beacons, run it in the background, and use another application to scan for said beacon, in the same phone as I have little experience in that field. Thank you.

I have tried using the locate application to broadcast and NRFconnect to scan but I was not able to detect the broadcasted beacons.

Comment: An iPhone app can act as an iBeacon but only on the foreground. It can advertise a BLE gatt service in the background

Answer (score 1):

Typically, no. Most phones (if not all), only have one physical Bluetooth radio which can therefore only perform one task (receive or transmit) at a time. Time scheduling is used if many tasks need to be done.

Therefore, when it sends advertisements, the scanner is disabled and vice versa. So you'll never receive your own advertisements.

Some kind of software loopback mechanism would be needed to solve this, which is not implemented on any platform as far as I know.